# Java SDK: Transaction object from envelope

Tags: javascript-sdk, java-sdk

In Javascript SDK, transaction can be built, signed and then be converted to envelope xdr/string format. This is very useful for multi sig operations since we can retrieve the transaction object from the transaction envelope.
https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Transaction.html

But I did not find the transaction creation from envelope function in Java SDK or C# SDK.

Any idea how to implement it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the C# SDK i believe there is not a method for parse an XDR into a transaction envelope thing yet, however i will be doing examples on the c# documentation and one of them is exactly that, so if there is not a method created i will try to code it.

Issue of the examples
https://github.com/elucidsoft/dotnet-stellar-sdk/issues/60

Documentation examples
https://elucidsoft.github.io/dotnet-stellar-sdk/examples/intro.html

Edit: It seems there is a issue for this https://github.com/elucidsoft/dotnet-stellar-sdk/issues/38

Edit2: This is going to make into the C# SDK soon.

Edit3: Added

Cheers

Comment: Hi, we ported it from the Java SDK to the C# SDK recently!

Answer (score 0):

Complete examples are not present for java SDK but they have given snippets ie your best place to find answers is java docs.

You can use this function **Class CreateAccountOperation** in stellar java sdk for account creation

https://stellar.github.io/java-stellar-sdk/